# Regex expression to capture text after a character and terminated by whitespace

Tags: regex

Looking for some help with a RegEx expression.  I want to parse a line similar to below, capturing the integer after the letter Q:

Q232.1232    K1232.232323

would be come 232.1232 ideally in output.

The expression /(^Q)[0-9.-]* .  provides me with Q232.1232 however i do not want the Q in the output.

Appreciate anyone who could assist!

Comment: Learn about `capturing groups`.

Comment: `232.1232` is not an integer. :-) Could you have `Q232 K1232.232323` or `Q232 K1232` or `Q232.1232` or `K1232.2323 Q232.1232`?

Comment: Something like this I guess `Q(\d+.?\d+)` and the use $1 to keep track of only the digits which has been captured

Comment: @Baldráni, you forgot to escape the period.

Comment: Capture what you need to extract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any group of characters enclosed in brackets will be captured. You can then use back-references to refer to these captured groups in the replacement expression.

So for your example, you would need

```
(^Q[0-9.-])*
```

back-references are normally accessed using $ or \, followed by the captured group number, $1 in your case

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
/(?<=Q)(?:\d+(?![.\d])|\d+\.\d+(?![.\d]))/gm
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/i6SuoD/3/)

`(?<=Q)` is a *positive lookbehind*. It requires the match to be immediately preceded by `"Q"`, but `"Q"` is not part of the match.

I've made assumptions about which strings can be matched. Those are reflected at the demo.

The regular expression can be written in *free-spacing mode* to make it self-documenting:

```
/
(?<=Q)       # match 'Q' in a positive lookbehind
(?:          # begin non-capture group
  \d+        # match representation of an integer (1+ digits)
  (?![.\d])  # do not match a period or digit (negative lookahead)
  |          # or
  \d+\.\d+   # match representation of a float
  (?![.\d])  # do not match a period or digit (negative lookahead)
)            # end non-capture group
/gmx         # global, multiline and free-spacing regex definition modes
```

Comment: I like the version in your comment better.